# How to download optimized image, css, javascript on google page speed insight

Tags: google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

previously google page speed insight used to give a link where we can download the optimized contents. now as of 19 dec 2018 i am not able to find that link because page speed insight has been updated with new features by google. if anyone know how to download the optimized images, css, javascript from google page speed insight please share your knowledge.
please suggest if any other online tool available.

Comment: Perhaps you mean "minified" contents, not "optimized" contents?. Your question is unclear and could also be off-topic

Comment: i think my question is clear here as i am asking about downloading optimized contents because google page speed insight used to give only a single link named  "download optimized images, javascript and css resources for this page". i think anyone with knowledge of google page speed insight will get the question clearly.

Comment: @NaveenSaroye yes this was use to be there but with new update i guess i am not seeing this now

Comment: thank you for your time....is there any other way or website where i can download all the optimized images for a page of my website without optimizing them manually.

Comment: i guess tinypng or relevent websites, but this will be manual work :)

Comment: just minify before deploying the files to the web-server... as it is common.

Comment: @Naveen Saroye : Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Jigar7521 nope. i am doing it the manual way. i will post a comment if i find any solution..

Comment: @NaveenSaroye  well I founded solution, let me post answer here as it's bit lengthy

Comment: @Jigar7521 i checked the website....it's good and fulfill the requirements. i am accepting this answer. thank you.

Comment: @NaveenSaroye Thanks but it was very important for me to find the solution, I faced every week this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As google has updated their page-speed insights version, 
>   they are not providing compressed files/images, but in older version they were providing
>   compressed images as well minified js & css files.

I have founded another solution regarding this but not at all, this not a complete solution, but you can utilise it.

Just go to https://www.sitereq.com/download-optimized-files

**Pest your particular page URL there and submit**

Below they will provide you compressed images and js/css files which are downloadable.

> **NOTE : You must have to open an account there first**

Best Regards.

Comment: I went through the process, found images that can be optimized, downloaded them... they're exactly the same size. :(

Answer (score 2):

The option was previously available but not anymore after the recent Google Pagespeed design update. Currently you need to check online compression tool for the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently optimized/minified files are not available any more on Google's Pagespeed Insights page.

You could use an alternative tool like [GTmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com), that will offer you minified versions of your css/js files as well as compressed versions of your images.
It is free to use and offers some added benefits, including a Yslow report (Yahoo's equivalent to Google's Pagespeed).

I personally use GTmetrix to optimize my pages, then test them on Google's Pagespeed Insights to make sure both results match.

Comment: lossless or glossy are not enough to pass google pagespeed test. i need lossy images. any other tool which provide lossy images...??